# '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-templates, form-fields

I want to run my code, however, I keep on getting error messages. 
It is about a form field in which they type in their value. If the value is within a specific range, they'll get 1 Euro. The code is:

```
class Guess(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['guess']

    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.round_number == 2

    def vars_for_template(self):
        if self.player.guess >= 11.25 and self.player.guess <= 13.75:
            self.player.cumulative_guthaben = self.player.cumulative_guthaben + 1
        else:
            self.player.cumulative_guthaben = self.player.cumulative_guthaben

            return {
                'current_credit': self.player.cumulative_guthaben,
                'anzahlspieler': Constants.number_of_players,
                'round_number': self.round_number,}
```

I do know that it is a type error, but I was not successful in fixing it

```
Here is a shorter Version of my Class: 
class Player(BasePlayer): 
guthaben = models.CurrencyField(initial=c(0)) 
cumulative_guthaben = models.CurrencyField() 
donation = models.FloatField(min=c(0)) 
earnedmoney = models.CurrencyField() 
frequency = models.StringField() 
rival = models.StringField() 
guess = models.FloatField(label="Your Guess:")
```

Comment: What is ````player.guess````?

Comment: 1) Please paste the full error traceback. The #1 useful thing when debugging is the FULL traceback, not the last line of it (it tells you exactly one line caused the issue). 2) From the looks of things, the code that is causing the issue is not in the chunk you pasted (it is in the player class).

Comment: Please don't open new questions until you have addressed the comments on your previous one (or closed it).

Comment: `self.player.guess` is `None`. To figure out why, you have to post more relevant code.

Comment: Here is a shorter Version of my Class: class Player(BasePlayer):
    guthaben = models.CurrencyField(initial=c(0))
    cumulative_guthaben = models.CurrencyField()
    donation = models.FloatField(min=c(0))
    earnedmoney = models.CurrencyField()
    frequency = models.StringField()
    rival = models.StringField()
    guess = models.FloatField(label="Your Guess:")

Comment: @daniel hepper: 
but why? I defined this as 
```
guess = models.FloatField(label="Your Guess:") 
```

Comment: Where is `self.player` defined? What does the `Page` base class do? Comments are no suited for multiline code, please edit your question to add code

Answer (score 1):

You get errors because at some point `self.player.guess` is NoneType and it should be float to compare it with a float. You can use `isinstance(i, type)`. You don't need else, as you don't change the value of `self.player.cumulative_guthaben`.
But you should check the rest of your code, why `self.player.guess` is NoneType.
Something like that:

```
class Guess(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['guess']
    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.round_number == 2

    def vars_for_template(self):
        if isinstance(self.player.guess, float):
            if (self.player.guess >= 11.25 and self.player.guess <= 13.75):
                self.player.cumulative_guthaben = self.player.cumulative_guthaben + 1
        return {
            'current_credit': self.player.cumulative_guthaben,
            'anzahlspieler': Constants.number_of_players,
            'round_number': self.round_number,}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help, this is not my code and I am a beginner. The strange part is that I only defined the variable guess in this short section and will not use it in another one. The only other time I saw it was in models.py as "guess = models.FloatField(label="Your Guess:")"